# Android + SDL2.0.5 + Admob Banner issue

Tags: admob, sdl, banner

It is a strange problem. Although admob banner appears in my SDL2 game, if i press home button on my Android tablet device to exit game and then return back, admob banner disappears. Home button prevents any banner from appearing. Then in order to make it appear again, i have to clear cache files. If i start my game, press home button to exit, come back and then try to load banner, it is also not appearing.

The code i use in activity java file is:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);

adView.setAdUnitId(myid);

adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
.build();

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

adView.loadAd(adRequest);

adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);   

mLayout.addView(adView, params);
```

And on build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile ‘com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1’
}

apply plugin: ‘com.google.gms.google-services’*
```

Comment: I found what caused this issue. I was using SDL_SetRenderTarget in my c++ SDL2 code to render directly to texture and this prevented admob banner from showing up after home button press. Now  on my activity onPause, i switch rendering from texture to main renderer and banners work fine. And onResume of activity i switch again to texture rendering.